# Tracing without breakpoints

Tags: ollydbg, tracing

I need:

1. To start tracing without breakpoints.
2. To do something in a program.
3. To stop tracing. This step may be replaced with a breakpoint but not the first step.

The thing is I need to do some actions in a program during tracing. I can't do this while it is paused.

How to do this in **OllyDbg**?
What debuggers support this if not this one?

Comment: If you just want to trace certain parts of the program may be you don't need a full debugger. My be a different system may suite better: e.g. a scriptable hooking system like https://frida.re which allows to hook functions, print arguments and later unload the hook.

Comment: @Robert I need this tracing mechanism: https://media.discordapp.net/attachments/360907625837101067/1040654669988515880/111.gif

Comment: Not sure what you want to tell me with that animated screenshot. May be my understanding of what is meant by "tracing" is different than yours. Please explain what tracing is from your perspective.

Comment: @Robert It is recording all steps. I don't think someone may understand this differently. I mean synchronization with the main tab (assembler), not just a list. It is just a feature which works in OllyDbg. It seems to be missing in x64dbg.